# How i upload angular project with json server on firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase, json-server

i upload angular 4 project to apatche server after build but it not working it get error it cant reach to js files

[image]

and try to upload it on firebase hosting but it can't access http request on http://localhost:3000/product/

[image]

Comment: Have you read that message about mixed content?

Comment: i changed localhost:3000 to domain but also not working

Comment: Once again: have you read that message? It tells you that you are mixing HTTPS and HTTP

Comment: yes pro and fix it but not working i need how to file.json as api in firebase